# How to update the displayed available options in Vue Multiselect after searching

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I have a vue multiselect with a custom search function. When I enter text to search, it updates the available options, but the available options displayed to the user don't change until they select one of the options. What do I need to do to get the multiselect options to refresh when you search the available options?

```
<v-row 
    v-for="(filter, idx) in campaign.filters.selected_filters"
      align="center"
      :key="idx"
      style="margin-top: 8px"
    >  
      <v-col cols="4" style="padding-top:25px"> <!-- First select -->
        <vue-multiselect
            v-model="filter.column"
            :options="temp_selected_filters[idx].availableColumns"
            @input="filterSelectionChanged(filter.column, idx)"
            :multiple="false"
            :close-on-select="true"
            :clear-on-select="false"
            :preserve-search="true"
            placeholder="Field"
            :show-labels="false"
            :internal-search="false"
            @search-change="(query) => searchTextChange(idx, query)"
            style="width:100%">
            
              <!-- Use the slot to display only the "text" part -->
              <template slot="option" slot-scope="{ option }">
                {{ getColumnObject(option).name }}
              </template>
            
              <!-- Use the slot to display only the "text" part of the selected item -->
              <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="{ option }">
                {{ getColumnObject(option).name }}
              </template>
            
        </vue-multiselect>
    // ... more items
```

Here is the search function:

```
searchTextChange(index, query) {
            this.temp_selected_filters[index].availableColumns = [];
            this.availableColumns.forEach(item => {
                const name = this.getColumnObject(item).name;
                if (name.toLowerCase().includes(query)) {
                    this.temp_selected_filters[index].availableColumns.push(item);
                }
            });
            this.temp_selected_filters[index].searchText = query;
        },
```

And here is the filterSelectionChanged function:

```
        filterSelectionChanged(column, index) {
            if (this.temp_selected_filters[index]) {
                const prev_selected_column = this.temp_selected_filters[index].column;
                // Either they unselected a previously selected filter, or added a new filter without selecting a column and typed in the value, or they changed the column and the new type is not the same as the old column type
                if ((!column && this.available_filters[prev_selected_column].type != 'string')
                    || (column &&
                        ((!prev_selected_column && this.available_filters[column].type != 'string')
                            || (prev_selected_column && this.available_filters[column].type != this.available_filters[prev_selected_column].type)))
                ) {
                    this.campaign.filters.selected_filters[index].value = '';
                }
            }
            this.temp_selected_filters[index].column = column;
            if (!this.getOperators(column).includes(this.campaign.filters.selected_filters[index].operator)) { // Reset the operator if user selects a column, picks an operator, then changes the column and the new column doesn't include the previously selected operator.
                this.campaign.filters.selected_filters[index].operator = '';
            }
        },
```

After entering search text, here is what temp_selected_filters might look like:

```
"0": {
        "column": null,
        "searchText": "email",
        "availableColumns": [
            "email",
            "manager_email",
            "personal_email"
        ]
    },
"1": {
        "column": "address",
        "searchText": "addr",
        "availableColumns": [
            "address",
            "work_address"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: If there's a correction needing to be made to your search/filter logic, we'll need to see it first.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77327322/edit) your question and include the relevant JS

Comment: @yoduh I have added these functions. What's in temp_selected_filters[idx].availableColumns is changing when I enter search text, it's just that what the user actually sees isn't updating until they select one of the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to call forceUpdate after the data in temp_selected_filters[idx].availableColumns changed:

```
searchTextChange(index, query) {
    this.temp_selected_filters[index].availableColumns = [];
    this.availableColumns.forEach(item => {
        const name = this.getColumnObject(item).name;
        if (name.toLowerCase().includes(query)) {
           this.temp_selected_filters[index].availableColumns.push(item);
        }
    });
    this.temp_selected_filters[index].searchText = query;
    this.$forceUpdate();
},
```